# Laravel relation between 3 models?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to define relations between 3 Models in Laravel.
I have Users, Documents and Permissions. A User can have many Documents and a Document can be assigned to many Users. That's the easy part, a many-to-many relation.

Now I have a Permission table with two entries, read and write.
I can't get my head around it, how to assign read or write permission to a document, based on the User.

For example:
User1 can write Document1 and read Document2
User2 can write both
User3 can only read both

Comment: You need to give role to user like editor , admin , viewer ..etc..

Comment: @Patrick Heppler Please share your db_table.

Comment: this tutorial link will help you Patrick : https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd there isn't a db_table yet. It's just in planning.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry roles won't work, because this would require two roles for each Document

Answer (score 2):

```
App\User::find(1)->documents()->save($document, 
                ['read' => true, 'write' => false]);
```

Also, in your models, add to your relationships:

```
->withPivot('document_id', 'user_id', 'read', 'write');
```

This would also be the fields of your table.

And than use

```
foreach ($user->documents as $document) {
    echo 'Can read: ' . $document->pivot->read;
}
```

For readability you could add a name to the pivot using:

```
->withPivot(...)->as('permissions')
```

And than access the pivot using:

```
foreach ($user->documents as $document) {
    echo 'Can read: ' . $document->permissions->read;
}
```

*Thanks to bogdan in the comments for the pivot name.*

Comment: To add to this solution, you can have `->withPivot(...)->as('permissions')`, and now you can use `$document->permissions->read` which makes it more readable.

Comment: @milo526 sorry for the delay. Your solution works great! Thanks.